# Select PDO query not working

Tags: php

Hi I am having a hard time figuring out why my simple select statement is returning a Boolean 0 for the $result and $row variable .

I have a database class :

```
<?php
class Database {
    private static $dsn='mysql:host=localhost;dbase=my_guitar_shop1';
    private static $username='mgs_user';
    private static $password='pa55word';
    private static $db;
    private function __construct(){}
    public static function getDB(){
        if(!isset(self::$db)){
            try {
                self::$db=new PDO ( self::$dsn, self::$username , self::$password);
            } catch (Exception $ex) {
                $error_message=$e->getMessage();
                include('../errors/database_error.php');
                exit();
            }
        }
        return self::$db;
    }
}
```

I have a CategoryDB class :

```
    <?php
class CategoryDB {
    public static function getCategories(){
     $db= Database::getDB();
     // Insert to Test
     $query= "INSERT INTO categories
              (categoryID, categoryName)
              VALUES ( 6,'test')";
     $statement= $db->prepare($query);
     $statement->execute();
     $query="SELECT * FROM categories";
     $statement=$db->prepare($query);
     $statement->execute();
     $row=$statement->fetch();


     $query= "SELECT * from categories";
     $statement= $db->prepare($query);
     $statement->execute();
     var_dump($statement);
     $result=$statement->fetchAll();
     var_dump($result);
     $statement->closeCursor();
     $categories=array();
     foreach($result as $row){
         $category=new Category($row['categoryID'],$row['categoryName']);
         $categories[]=$category;
     }
        return $categories;
    }
    public static function getCategory($category_id){
        $db=Database::getDB();
        $query="SELECT * from category
                WHERE categoryID=:category_id";
        $statement= $db->prepare($query);
        $statement->bindValue(':category_id', "$category_id");
        $statement->execute();
        var_dump($statement);
        $row=$statement->fetch();
        var_dump($row);
        $statement->closeCursor();
        $category=new Category($row['categoryID'],$row['categoryName']);
        return $category;
    }
}
```

The query to the database is not working .I traced the code and found that the $result and $row variables for getCategories() and getCategory() functions respectively is a Boolean 0 . $db is a PDO object . Could someone please help me why the queries are not working ?
On var dump of the two variables I get :

```
object(PDO)[1]

array (size=0)
  empty
boolean false
```

On `var_dump` of the two `$statement` variables in the two functions I get :

```
object(PDOStatement)[2]
public 'queryString' => string 'SELECT * from categories' (length=24)

object(PDOStatement)[3]
  public 'queryString' => string 'SELECT * from category
                WHERE categoryID=:category_id' (length=68)
```

Comment: What is the output you get when you use `var_dump()` on the return value of your `$statement->execute();` call? What is the output of `var_dump()` on your `fetchAll();` and `fetch();` calls? Please edit your question to include the additional debug information. Btw.: You don't need a prepared statement for the `getCategories()` method, is has no variables/user input, it's a fixed query.

Comment: `$category_id` will not work inside single quotes - either remove the quotes or convert them to double quotes.

Comment: Thanks changed it but the problem is not related to that . The first function should have worked .

Comment: @Knownow When you `SELECT * from categories` return "array (size=0) empty", then your table has no rows. This also means that your `fetch()` call from the other method will return `false` when there are no rows.

Comment: That is surprising . I am seeing the table and the columns . This is  Xamp . Another file is able to access the db but when I try with a simple SELECT from that table ( for testing ) it is not working . How does one troubleshoot this type of database issue ? will enabling logging help ? Sorry to sound stupid but I am new to this .

Comment: @Knownow You can try running an `INSERT` query before that so you know that there is at least one row in the table. Currently there aren't any rows.

Comment: @Progman inserting values is working . I am seeing the inserted values into the table along with the older values .

Comment: @Knownow So, the SELECT statements are working now? Please edit your question to include the source code you have now which INSERTs and SELECTs the rows.

Comment: @Progman- After I did the insert the select statement started working . The data I inserted got inserted to the database along with  with the old data which I was not able to access using the SELECT statement before . Any idea why that would happen ? I have edited my code . thanks for all the help all this time .